# Update the observable value on API request

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I'm using an observable to emit the values from a API.
Now in the component where its subscribed to i want to update the observable value on some event.

I'm not able to understand how to to it.

Below is the code in the service class

```
 cacheSettingsData$: Observable<any>;

     public getUserSettings() {
        if (!this.cacheSettingsData$) {
          this.cacheSettingsData$.next(this.requestUserSettings());
          this.userSettings = this.cacheSettingsData$;
        }
        return this.cacheSettingsData$;
      }
```

The requestUserSettings does the API Call and return the value

```
requestUserSettings(): Observable<any> {

    let httpHeader = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      })
    };
    return this.http.get(userSettUrl, httpHeader).pipe(
      map((response) => Object(response['settings'])),
      catchError(error => this.handleError(error)), shareReplay()
    );
```

Now in the component where the **getUserSettings** is subscribed how can i update the value of the observable  **cacheSettingsData$** on some event like when a button is clicked?

Please Guide!

Thanks
Shruti Nair

Comment: You want to update cached observable when you tigger some action?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood this properly you want to store on `this.userSettings` the result of the value emitted by the observable returned by `requestUserSettings()`. As your `requestUserSettings()` is returning a stream and you want to get those values into `cacheSettingsData$` to then set those values to `this.useSettings`. I think you don't even need this.cacheSettingsData$ because looks like you just want to load the user settings once and cache it on `this.userSettings`. So I would suggest something like this

```js
// in this case this method name is not the best
public getUserSettings() {
    if (!this.userSettings) {
        this.requestUserSettings().subscribe(settings => {
            this.userSettings = settings
        })
    }
}
```

Of course I don't know your project context so it's up to you to consider what better fits your requirements.